# Nuget causing building problems

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I have fork a project (NRefactory - https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory)
but I'm not able to build the solution.

Here's what the errors I'm getting from VS

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       The command "C:\Users\Kavignon_Developer\Documents\GitHub Projects\GitHub - Open Source Projects\SummerOfCode_2015\\.nuget\NuGet.exe restore -SolutionDirectory .." exited with code 9009.  ICSharpCode.NRefactory6.CSharp  C:\Users\Kavignon_Developer\Documents\GitHub Projects\GitHub - Open Source Projects\SummerOfCode_2015\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp\ICSharpCode.NRefactory6.CSharp.csproj   599
```

From some posts

1. [NuGet.exe install error 9009 - Downloaded Git repo won't build - mono--runtime=v4.0.30319](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168481/nuget-exe-install-error-9009-downloaded-git-repo-wont-build-mono-runtime-v)
2. [nuget install exit code 9009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097538/nuget-install-exit-code-9009)

I have figured that my nuget was faulty or missing. After getting into the nuget manager for my solution, nuget proposed to fix the missing packages in my solution. Thought it was a great option so I said yes. The thing is, it did not change the situation. I have rebuild and cleaned the solution but it did not have an impact.

Some might tell me that I don't have the nuget executable, but how could I manage to install nuget package without it ? Plus, going through the search function within windows, I was able to find the .exe of nuget.

What it is supposed to be done here? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6. I have no choice as I'm working with new feature in VS.

Comment: Open the csproj up in a text editor and go to line 599. That will be the missing file I suspect

Comment: Basically, if I were to be in that peculiar situation, all that is needed is to open the csproj? The file one the number you've given, what does it do ? It says that filenameX should be there and isnt, what should be done ? @garryp

Comment: This is what I have on line 599 : "     <Exec Condition="$(SolutionDir) != $([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('..'))" Command="$(NuGet) restore -SolutionDirectory .." />"
I don't really understand what to do from that though  @garryp

Comment: Have you tried running the poweshell command given in the reply to the first link you supplied in your OP? Also make sure you are running VS as admin.

Comment: @garryp I did do that, but it had no impact on the situation which is starting to get on my nerves because I don't really understand what's happening.
I have another forked project from GitHub, but I can build THAT solution compared to the one that I've described in my OP
I'm running out of things to do and I really want this to work.

For the fun of it, I downloaded VS 2013 Community, knowing fully that DiagnosticAnalyzer are just a part of 2015, but even with that version of VS, I am unable to build my solution and I have the same error on VS 2013 and VS 2015

Comment: I would recommend updating to latest version of VS2015 - namely the RC. I had NuGet problems and reported an issue - after updating to the RC, issues were solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939947/could-not-resolve-this-reference-nuget-on-ci-server/29960616#29960616

Comment: I have just seen it ! I've been in the process of uninstalling my VS Ultimate ctp. I really hope it does the work !

Comment: @spike It did not have any impact on my machine.I have the same error message. I don't know if the OP has the same issue too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is indeed a bug, as mentioned by a user in the comments (spike), within the NuGet executable. It looks like a borked installation of NuGet. The only way that I found to get rid of this is to completely reinstall your OS (please save before your precious data) and then install back again Visual Studio 2015 RC or an more up to date version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I used the Visual Studio 2015 RC Entreprise edition.
I don't know if the Community edition works. It took a long while installing again Visual Studio on my work station, and I did not want to verify, as a proof of concept, that it work with the other edition too. 
I will leave the matter in the hands of the OP and others that might suffer from the same issue.

Comment: Well, thankfully, I did not have to reinstall the OS. I had a project with `.nuget` and `nuget.exe` in source control and got rid of that first ( here's how: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore ) - because it's good practice and it ensures not calling an old version of the `nuget.exe`. Then I got rid of all local nuget caches ( search for .nupkg and clean up the whole folder ). Did this both locally and on CI server. Then I `install-package --force` the package that gave the issue and noticed that the hintpath had the additional `.0`.

Answer (score 0):

it is an old question but someone else also end up in this page when they are trying to solve nuget package build integration problem.

before throwing the towel, run nuget.exe command from command-prompt like you define in your project file in your project folder

> nuget pack ****.Common.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release

nuget.exe will give you more detailed error, in my example problem Bin\Release folder was missing

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Attempting to build package from '*****.csproj'.
Unable to find 'C:\Repositories********** \bin\Release\ ****.Common.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.
this won't be the answer for all errors but running nuget.exe will give you a better understanding of what is the error on build