# Could not resolve this reference: NuGet on CI server

Tags: .net, tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package-restore

I'm running a CI build on a TFS build controller, connected to VS Online. I've got a 'Could not resolve this reference' problem for a NuGet package and I've observed behavior that I haven't seen before:

Locally the pacakage is downloaded to `packages\FluentValidation.5.5.0` whereas on the server,  it's downloaded to `packages\FluentValidation.5.5.0.0`.

Packages.config:

```
<package id="FluentValidation" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net45" userInstalled="true" />
```

.csproj file `$(SolutionDir)` for shared project - works for all the other projects:

```
<Reference Include="FluentValidation, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">     
<HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\FluentValidation.5.5.0\lib\Net40\FluentValidation.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Nuget package restore is enabled, so if I locally remove the package from the packages folder and rebuild - works fine.

Now on the CI server. Build diagnostics log states:

> Installing 'FluentValidation 5.5.0.0'. 
>   ... 
>   Successfully installed 'FluentValidation 5.5.0.0'.

But then further in build log:

> 16>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "FluentValidation". Check to make sure the assembly
>   exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may
>   get compilation errors. [C:\Builds\24353... stuff...\projectfile.csproj]
>                    For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
>                    Considered "C:\Builds\24353... stuff ...\packages\FluentValidation.5.5.0\lib\Net40\FluentValidation.dll",

As expected - there's not package in that folder

`C:\Builds\24353\... stuff ...\packages\FluentValidation.5.5.0\lib\Net40\`.

However - that's because it is downloaded into a different folder on the CI server:

`C:\Builds\24353\... stuff ...\packages\FluentValidation.5.5.0.0\lib\Net40\`.

( note the extra .0 behind the package folder name ).

I have no idea where that extra .0 comes from. Also the project seems to ignore the build path. 
The CI server has VS 2013 on it and I updated NuGet on the box, didn't help. There's only 1 place where there's 5.5.0.0 ( with 2 zeros ) that's in the reference. I removed the trailing .0. Solution still builds locally, but not on CI.

[image: local packages folder left - server right]

**Update**
Adding a 2nd hintpath in the .csproj file seems to fix the build on CI server, but breaks it locally. I really can't get my head around why it's v5.0.0 locally and v5.0.0.0 on the CI server.

**P.S.** I've reported it as bug: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/504

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in NuGet, which is fixed in the VS2015 RC:

[image: Bug comment]

Source: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/504