# The command "npm install -- loglevel=error" exited with 9009

Tags: visual-studio, npm

I am trying to run the "[PartsUnlimited](https://github.com/Microsoft/PartsUnlimited)" project that I have cloned from GitHub and it gives me this error

> The command "npm install -- loglevel=error" exited with 9009

I really can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nuget install exit code 9009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097538/nuget-install-exit-code-9009)

Comment: @Amy Hi Amy. But my error is totally different than the link you provided..

Comment: npm install exited with 9009 is totally different how?

Comment: Error 9009 only tells you that the build event failed.  Exactly why it does not know, all it could see was that the process exit code was not 0.  You must look in the Output window for a diagnostic message produced by that program.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Node.js solved this error on Visual Studio 2022.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/