# The command " run C:\agent\_work\8\s\Web\webapi.nswag" exited with code 9009

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a project with NSwagger installed. 
Here is my .csporj configuration:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\NSwag.MSBuild.11.15.3\build\NSwag.MSBuild.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\NSwag.MSBuild.11.15.3\build\NSwag.MSBuild.props'))" />
</Target>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe) run $(SolutionDir)webapi.nswag" />
</Target>
```

Error :

> ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
>     Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
>   Project "C:\agent_work\8\s\Web\CSU.Marketplace.Web.sln" (1) is building "C:\agent_work\8\s\Web\CSU.Marketplace.Web\CSU.Marketplace.Web.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>   BeforeBuild:
>      run C:\agent_work\8\s\Web\webapi.nswag
>     'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.
>   Web\CSU.Marketplace.Web\CSU.Marketplace.Web.csproj(942,5): Error MSB3073: The command " run C:\agent_work\8\s\Web\webapi.nswag" exited with code 9009.

Comment: Your post has no question and have you looked up meaning of code 9009?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097538/nuget-install-exit-code-9009

Answer (score 3):

The project file does not import the NSwag build tasks.
Therefore at build time, $(NSwagExe) expands to an empty string, and msbuild tries to run the rest of the command:

*run C:\agent_work\8\s\Web\webapi.nswag*

Add something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.MSBuild" Version="11.12.9" />
</ItemGroup>
```